# Rewrite .htaccess rule for .php ext into non-existing .html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two .php files that used to be in .html and are now .php, so I have to read them as .html for SEO reasons.

abcd.php into non-existing abcd.html
and
efgh.php in non-existing efgh.html with simple htaccess just for those two specific .php, not all of them?

In my htaccess file there is also a rule for redirecting http into https for one domain, the same for SEO issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xxxxxx.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxxxx.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post from which url to which url you want to rewrite?

Comment: OK, lets say from `https://www.example.com/nameofpage_A.php to https://www.example.com/nameofpage_A.html and from https://www.example.com/nameofpage_B.php to https://www.example.com/nameofpage_B.html` Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to call https://www.example.com/page_A.html in Browser, but apache2 runs /page_A.php ?

Comment: I want to call for example example.com/page_A.html in Browser, but server runs example.com/page_A.php. So I type in browser example.com/page_A.html and it read example.com/page_A.php. Beside page_A.html don't exist on server, just page_A.php.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html?$ $1.php [L]
```

With this in .htaccess, any browser request https://www.example.com/page_A.html makes apache2 to run https://www.example.com/page_A.php instead.

Comment: I had something like that before, no, it rewrite page_A.php extension to page page_A.html, but any other .html page on my server is stop working. That's why I want this rewrite just for two pages, not in general all .php to .html. So page_A.php into non existing page_A.html and page_B.php into non existing page_B.html.